# Is a random variable considered "identical" if it can choose a value from a sample space containing values of differing probabilities?

Tags: probability, statistics

I can't seem to find a consistent definition of an "identically distributed" random variable.

Lets say my random variable equals the SUM of two dice rolls:

$X = \textrm{Sum of the scores on two dice}$

The Sample Space = $\{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12\}$ with respective probabilities of $\{1/36, 1/18, 1/12, 1/9, 5/36, 1/6, 5/36, 1/12, 1/18, 1/36\}$

SO, is this particular random variable considered "identically distributed" even though it can adopt values with varying probabilities?

If so, what is an example of a NON-identically distributed random variable?

Comment: Identically distributed is defined for a sequence of random variables. It doesn't really make sense to define it for a single random variable.

Comment: Or even just a pair of random variables.  This particular random variable isn't identically distributed by itself.

Comment: I suppose that, trivially, every random variable is identically distributed to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identically distributed refers to when you compare multiple random variables, not just looking at one. You may be confusing it with a "uniform" random variable, which is one where all possible outcomes have the same probability.

Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed if, for all possible outcomes $e$, $P(X = e) = P(Y = e)$. For example, if $X$ and $Y$ represent the colour of an American roulette wheel spin, then it might be that $P(X = black) = \frac{18}{38} = P(Y = black)$, and similarly $P(X = red) = \frac{18}{38} = P(Y = red)$ and $P(X = green) = \frac{2}{38} = P(Y = green)$, so $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed. By comparison, if $Z$ is the colour of a French roulette wheel, because they only have one green space, $P(Z = black) = P(Z = red) = \frac{18}{37}$ and $P(Z = green) = \frac{1}{37}$, so while $X$ and $Z$ have the same sample space, they are not identically distributed.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Does random variable X describe the probability of the spin landing on red and and random variable Y describe the probability of the spin landing on black? Why do you have X being equal to red and black? What random event are these random variables describing?

Comment: X is the colour the first spin gets, Y is the colour the second spin gets. Z is also the colour of spinning a wheel, but it's from spinning a differently distributed one.